# comparing averages in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables; One that contains students `names` and `sids` and the other is a "take" table containing the `sids of students` and their `grades`.

I want to show the names of students who have average greater than that of a student name "Peter-Parker".

I have tried the query below, but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT s.sid, s.fname, s.lname
FROM student s, take t
WHERE s.sid = t.sid AND AVG(t.grade) > ALL(
SELECT AVG(grade)
FROM take, student
WHERE student.fname = 'Ali' and student.lname='Demir');
 WITH AliAv(avg) AS
 (SELECT AVG(grade) from take t, student s
 where t.sid = s.sid ands.fname = 'Ali' and s.lname = 'Demir')
 select student.sid, student.fname, student.lname
 from student, take
 where student.sid = take.sid Group by student.sid
 having avg(take.grade) > AliAv.av;
```

Comment: I guess that `'Ali Demir'` is Peter Parker's nickname? I thought it was Spider Man.

Comment: Why are you using the `with` syntax in MySQL?  It doesn't support CTEs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT s.sid, s.fname, s.lname, AVG(t.grade) AS average
FROM student AS s
JOIN take AS t ON t.sid = s.sid
GROUP BY s.sid
HAVING average > (
    SELECT AVG(t2.grade)
    FROM student AS s2
    JOIN take AS t2 ON t2.sid = s2.sid
    WHERE s2.fname = 'Peter' and s2.lname = 'Parker'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in SQL Server, I don't know if the syntax is valid in MySQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM Student s
WHERE
  (SELECT AVG(Grade) FROM Take WHERE SID=s.ID) > (SELECT AVG(Grade) FROM Take WHERE SID = (SELECT SID FROM Student WHERE FName='Peter' AND LName='Parker'))
```